# How to define a datatype of a fixed size in bits in C Programming language

Tags: c

Say for n = 4, we need to define a data type A, such that the size of A becomes **4 bits**. I know we can do this thing by using structures 
like by the following code

```
struct Bit
{
    unsigned int a:4;
} dat;
```

Here dat will  store the integers having the maximum size of 4 bits i.e. will store from 0 to 15, but if we use sizeof operator,

```
sizeof(dat);
```

this will give value to 4(in gcc) which corresponds to 4 bytes i.e. 32 bits, but I need some way to define dat variable to be of size 4 bits.

Comment: `char` is the smallest type and the granulartity of addressing (`sizeof(char) == 1` is guaranteed). This is an XY-problem. Please state your **actual** problem.

Comment: That's impossible. Nothing can be smaller than a `char`. `unsigned int a: 4` does not mean "this is 4 bits", but "4 bits of this `unsigned int` are called 'a'". The remaining bits still exist but are unnamed.

Comment: On a side-note, what could `sizeof(foo)` evaluate to with a 4-bit `foo` ?

Comment: @Quentin `0.5f`, obviously!

Comment: @ElderBug Why the value should be `float`, not `double` or `long double`?

Comment: @ElderBug: I suppose those 0.5 Bytes are 500 millibytes, or 4000 millibits?

Comment: @tofro No! Don't be like these hard drive marketing depts! We must count it in power of 2, so it's 512 miblibytes, or 4096 miblibits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In he C standard and with current mainstream computers you can't. On all commonly used hardware the Word Size, the "native" data size the CPU can work on is 8 bit or a multitude (16, 32, 64) of this. Historically computers used other word sizes (like 9 or 12), too, bu I'm not aware of a modern machine with less than 8 bits per word.

The smallest integral type current C standards describe is an (u)int8_t with 8 bits.

With your example of

```
struct Bit
{
    unsigned int a:4;
} dat;
```

There is no requirement of a minimal or maximum size of this in the standard. The CPU will however need requirements. For one he uint it gets has to be a a multiple of 8.

Now if we where doing

```
struct Bit
{
    unsigned int a:4;
    unsigned int b:4;
} dat;
```

The compiler might but those to fields into the same 8 bit region and add the required shift on all operations, but this is not strictly required. A compiler could also put this into two different words.

There's no way to access less than a word.

Comment: Usually, a 'word' is different from a byte. For x86/x64, the word size is sometime said to be 32-bits or 64-bits, but in the documentations, a 'word' is 16-bits. 'word' probably shouldn't be used at all here, it's ambiguous. The term used in the C standard is 'byte' for the smallest addressable unit, which is often an octet.

Answer (score -3):

This is architecture dependent. Most of processors can not access memory that is less than byte, and well in your case 32 bits is probably smallest chunk of memory.

Comment: *"in your case 32 bits is probably smallest chunk of memory"* Unless OP is using some very obscure arcitechture where `sizeof(char) == sizeof(unsigned int) == 1` and `CHAR_BIT == 32`; this is very unlikely.

Answer (score -3):

The size here, is 32 bits because, you seem to be using a 32 bit machine and in every cycle, 32 bits is read (the additional 28 bits are the padding bits added by the OS).

Comment: Disabling padding doesn't help on bit level.